# Links not working with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

My link won't work, it seems to be ok but when I click on it nothing happens. However, when I put the mouse on it the target is printed and is correct.

The strange thing is that I did exactly the same thing on an other part of the website and I work fine.
Here is my code :

```
<!-- === Slide 5 === -->
<div class="slide story" id="slide-5" data-slide="5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row title-row">
            <div class="col-12 font-thin">Nos <span class="font-semibold">suggestions</span> de véhicules</div>
        </div><!-- /row -->
        <div class="row line-row">
            <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
        </div><!-- /row -->
        <div class="row subtitle-row">
            <div class="col-12 font-thin">Vous souhaiteriez <span class="font-semibold">commander</span> un véhicule, vous ne savez pas par ou commencer, vous aimeriez des <span class="font-semibold">idées</span> ? </div>
        </div><!-- /row -->
        <div class="row content-row">

            <?php
            // Connexion à la base de données
            try
            {
                $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=collaborateurs;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
            }

            // Récupération des  messages
            $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT id, marque, modele, description, lien, nom_image FROM suggestions ORDER BY id');

            while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
            {
            ?>
                <div class="grid_4 col-4 col-sm-6" id="card<?php echo $donnees['id']; ?>">
                    <div class="box">
                        <a class="gall_item"><img src="images/Suggestions/<?php echo $donnees['nom_image']; ?>" alt=""><span></span></a>
                        <div class="box_bot">
                            <div class="box_bot_title"><i class="icon icon-hand-up pull-left"></i><?php echo $donnees['marque']; ?>, <?php echo $donnees['modele']; ?></div>
                            <p><?php echo $donnees['description']; ?></p>
                            <div>
                                <a href="<?php echo $donnees['lien']; ?>" class="btn" >Détails</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }

            $reponse->closeCursor();
            ?>

        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /slide5 -->
```

Comment: can you remove the class "btn" and try again ?

Comment: What is in `$donnees['lien']`?

Comment: I tried removing btn or changing a by button but it doesn't work and in $donnees['lien'] I've put a link on an other website which is ok I already checked that

Comment: Check JavaScript console - it sounds like a conflict elsewhere in your code.

Comment: the console doesn't give any errors with it. and this part doesn't user js so...

Comment: Try escaping everything that is echoed as advised, and if you still have a problem, post your HTML output. You will need to @ me if you want me to see your replies.

Comment: All the echo works and the one in the link seems to work too cause if I right click on my link and choose open in a new tab it works but when I try to put target="_blank" or _new it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

`$donnees['lien']` is likely breaking your code.

Try:

```
<?php echo html($donnees['lien']); ?>
```

And include this function in your config file:

```
function html($str){
  return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't change anything. And I think I don't need the special chars cause I'm changing myself the database so It should be ok in it

Comment: @Pierre You should always escape values to account for errors, not just for security.

Comment: Ok yes I will do that

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, I found the hyper link's destination is got from $donnees['lien'], 
Since we can not know what is it, I suggest you inspect your pages via developer tools(CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome) to see what value is the href.

BTW. Commonly, The href attribute is usually designed like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'cards/'.$card_name; ?>" class="btn"><?php echo $card_name;?></a>
```

note: base_url() returns your sites url, e.g. your site is www.xxx.com, and then your $card_name = "joker", the link will be:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/cards/joker" class="btn">joker</a>
```

Comment: I looked in the developer tools and the link is the right one. It's just doing nothing when we click on it. And the base_url won't work because the link doesn't target my website. It is supposed to go on another one

Comment: @Pierre Don't copy base_url(), it's just a example, then I suggest you hard code the link, just copy your $donnees['lien'] value in database to your pages to see if it will be work.  And also check your page's extension name, is it php?

Comment: yes I know it's an example. and yes all my page's extension are php

Comment: I tried by copying the content of $donnees['lien'] in href but it still doesn't work so the problem isn't php

Comment: @Pierre Then you can paste "http://stackoverflow.com" to your href, if it still does not work,  the problem may in your php file, javascript, your browser other than the a link.